# Getting VM metrics from Vcenter

Tags: python, vmware-vsphere

Is there a way to get VM information like resource utilization metrics from Vcenter server via an API ? I want to query them from a python script and I don't want to get them from powerCli.
Vsphere version - 5.5

Comment: Your google-foo is poor - look at this; https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/sdk/60/vcloudsuite-python

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python maybe [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) can help you.

If it's lacking the functionality you need you can always use the [SOAP based API](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/right-pane.html) directly.

And have a look at the [VMware Developer Center](https://developercenter.vmware.com/) / [VMware Sample Exchange](https://developercenter.vmware.com/samples), maybe you can find some interesting things there.